# Number base conversion with exception handling

Tags: javascript

I have a function that converts a string representation of number of any valid number base and its radix. How do I correctly handle invalid numbers (like using A-K chars in bases < 11)? In invalid cases, I would like to return -1.

So far, I was able to achieve some degree of success with isNan() check, but it breaks on decimal base (convert("5A6E", 10)).

My code so far:

```
function convert(strNumber, radix) {
  a = parseInt(strNumber, radix) 

  if(isNaN(a)){
    return -1
  }
  else {
    return a
  }
}
```

Comment: Fails how? `convert("5A6E", 10)` returns `5`.

Comment: Thats the problem I guess, if I understand number bases correctly, "5A6E" shouldn't be a valid number in decimal base as it consist of 0-9. Do I have this wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your breakage example "5A6E" you get back 5 because that's how parseInt works - see the examples in the documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

At the bottom of the above page, you will find a section titled "A stricter parse function" it appears to do what you are looking for using RegEx.

Update: In thinking about this further, the "Stricker parse function" is only going to work for base 10. To be more flexible you should add a function that looks at the radix, and based on that, checks for invalid characters in strNumber, returning -1 if any are found and calling parseInt if not.

For instance, if radix = 2, all characters except 0 and 1 are invalid. If it's 11, all characters but 0-9 and 'a' are invalid.

Tedious, but it will do what you want.

Comment: I was thinking about that in the begining but I wanted to asked whether there is a more elegant solution. Thank you for the info though.